# Laravel 5.1 Basic Task List / NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 error

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-artisan

I am a laravel newbie and I'm trying to do the basic task list lesson in the laravel 5.1 docs and I get this error: **NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161.**

This is the lesson I'm trying to do:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart

I did exactly what the lesson said, copied everything line by line and I still don't know why this is happening.

These are my routes. I have a feeling that my error is somewhere there or I might be totally wrong.

```
use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
/**
 * Show Task Dashboard
 */
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('tasks', [
        'tasks' => Task::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get()
    ]);
});

/**
 * Add New Task
 */
Route::post('/task', function (Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $task = new Task;
    $task->name = $request->name;
    $task->save();

    return redirect('/');
});

/**
 * Delete Task
 */
Route::delete('/task/{id}', function ($id) {
    Task::findOrFail($id)->delete();

    return redirect('/');
});
```

});

And this is where I go to the browser and get the error: http://localhost:8000/tasks

Maybe my URL in my browser is wrong
I've also tried with localhost:8000/laravel-uni-project/public/tasks

As I mentioned above I copied everything from the tutorial exactly as it said, so I may have an error somewhere else in my application.

p.s. the tutorial is for laravel 5.1 and I'm using 5.1 as well.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't really see a route to tasks here, just task.  To list all the tasks you just go to / according to the above.

Answer (score 0):

you are browsing task,but in your routes file there is not route for task get request,may be that will your task get request.

```
Route::get('/tasks', function () {
return view('tasks', [
    'tasks' => Task::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get()
]);
});
```

Comment: m8 I doubled checked an it actually works. Thank you